# Get iframe elements from other iframe string

Tags: iframe

I have 3 nested iframes and I want to get to access to element (link) in third  iframe.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('aswift_2');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

var secondIframe = innerDoc.getElementById('google_ads_frame3');
var secondinnerDoc = secondIframe.contentDocument || secondIframe.contentWindow.document;

var treedIframe = document.getElementById('ad_iframe');
var secondinnerDoc = treedIframe.contentDocument || treedIframe.contentWindow.document;

var Link = secondinnerDoc.getElementById('aw0');
```

But I got error when trying to access.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63342" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

How I can access to `<a>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while for me, but I believe this is due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This policy which is built in to the browser does not let you access content in an iframe unless the iframe comes from the same domain, protocol, port, etc as the outer page. This prevents a malicious developer from having an iframe of say the Google login page, and you accessing the password field contents with JavaScript (one example of [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

The answer would be that this isn't possible unless the iframe pages are all on the same domain.